# Effect size for comparison of two nested models

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, effect-size, model-comparison, nested-models

I want to calculate an effect size for the difference of two structural equation models (model 1 and 2). Model 2 is nested in model 1.

For each model I get a $\chi^2$ as measure of fit. Whether the nested model fits better than the original model can be tested by calculating $\Delta\chi^2$ $= \chi_1^2 - \chi_2^2$ and the corresponding $p$ value (based on the corresponding degrees of freedom of both models: $df_1$ and $df_2$).

However, now I want to quantify the magnitude of the difference between both $\chi^2$. I did some research and found this [document](http://www.upa.pdx.edu/IOA/newsom/semclass/ho_nested.pdf). The author defines

$w = \sqrt{\frac{\Delta\chi^2}{N\cdot\Delta df}}$

as effect size for the difference between two models (whereby $N =$ sample size and $\Delta df = df_1 - df_2$).

Unfortunately, I did not yet find another reference where this equation is used.

**I therefore have two questions:**

1. **Its the definition of $w$ as effect size of the difference between two models correct?**
2. **Can somebody point out additional references that use or describe this effect size measure?**

---

A little 'add on' for everyone working with `lavaan`:

```r
    ## Comparison between model 1 and model 2
    ## model1 contains the fitted model 1 (model1 <- cfa(...))
    ## model2 contains the fitted model 2 (model2 <- cfa(...))
    
    modelcomp <- anova(model1, model2)
    
    # Calculate effect size measure
    # dataset = used data set
    
    w <- sqrt(modelcomp$'Chisq diff'[2] / 
            (nrow(dataset) * modelcomp$'Df diff'[2]))
    
    w
```

---

**Edit:**

On a second glance the formula for $w$ looks like the formula normally used for Cramer's $V$ ([see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%27s_V)). However, I am not fully sure how to get the $\Delta df$ in the denominator. Any ideas?